# Overwrite multiple partitions at once Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a partitioned external table Hive that i have to overwrite with some records.
There are a lot of dates that we need to reload and the queries are a bit heavy.
What we want to know is if it is possible, in a simultaneous way load two or more different partitions at the same time?
For example, 3 (or more) processes running in parallel like:

**Process1**

```
insert overwrite table_prod partition (data_date)
select * from table_old where data_date=20221110;
```

**Process2**

```
insert overwrite table_prod partition (data_date)
select * from table_old where data_date=20221111;
```

**Process3**

```
insert overwrite table_prod partition (data_date)
select * from table_old where data_date=20221112;
```

Comment: Why can't you write a shell script loop to run these queries in parallel processes?

Comment: We just have it in a loop, but it was running sequentially and we wanted first to see if it was feasible to run in parallel because we were not sure if hadoop would present problems by the concurrency of overwrites on the same table even if they were different partitions. We already had something launching processes in parallel from unix, here I leave the script.

Comment: cores=10
for fecha in $(hive --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e 'show partitions sandbox_datascientist.am_cdr_datasets;' | cut -d"=" -f2); do
 hive --hivevar FECHA=${fecha} -f "${PATH_SQL}/insert_cdr_datasets.sql" 1>ins.err 2>ins.out &
 while :; do
  background=( $(jobs -p))
  if (( ${#background[@]} < $cores )); then
   break
  fi
  sleep 1
 done
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is yes you can.

Real question is how - because you have to consider large volume of data.

Option 1 - yes, you can use shell script or some scheduler tool. But the query you're using is going to be slow. you can use static partitioning which is way faster.

```
insert overwrite table_prod partition (data_date=20221110) -- pls note i mentioned partition value.
select 
col1, col2... -- exclude data_date column from select list
from table_old where data_date=20221110;
```

Option 2 - You can also use dynamic partition scheme to load all the partitions at once. This is perf intensive operation but you dont have to create any shell script or any other process.

```
insert overwrite table_prod partition (data_date)
select * from table_old
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Koushik Roy. Using the static partition, from 20 minutes that lasted a day, it went to almost 2 minutes per day and that's a golazo. We just tested with a whole month running 7 days in parallel and it's flying!!!

Comment: if its `golazo`, then i hope i helped you :)...